# Electromagnetic stress tensor is only traceless in 4D?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics, classical-electrodynamics, trace

The electromagnetic stress tensor $F_{\mu \nu}$ is as we all know traceless in 4 dimensions. With $F_{\mu \nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu$ and $A = (A_0,A_1,A_2,A_3)= (\phi, A_1, A_2, A_3 )$

In other dimensions this is not the case? If so how does one expand either the definition of $F_{\mu \nu}$ and A?

Edit: I was clearly wrong with the with terminology, I meant the electromagnetic stress-energy tensor (or electromagnetic energy-momentum tensor) which was pointed out in the comment section.

Comment: Wouldn't $F_\mu^\mu = \partial_\mu A^\mu - \partial^\mu A_\mu = \partial_\mu A^\mu - \partial_\mu A^\mu = 0$?

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if you confused the terminology, but I'll address both interpretations of your question.

$F_{\mu \nu}$ is called the [Faraday/electromagnetic/field strength tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor). Its antisymmetric property does not depend on the number of dimensions, so it is always traceless. See also the answer by @J. Murray above.

On the other hand, the [electromagnetic stress-energy tensor (or electromagnetic energy-momentum tensor)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) is the tensor that you get by varying the Maxwell action with respect to the metric. In $d$ dimensions, it is given by:

$$T^\alpha_{\ \beta} = \frac{1}{4 \pi} \left( F^{\alpha \mu} F_{\beta \mu} - \frac{1}{4} \delta^\alpha_{\ \beta} F^{\mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu} \right)$$

Its trace is then:

$$T = \frac{1}{4 \pi}F^{\mu \nu}F_{\mu \nu} \left( \frac{4-d}{4} \right)$$

which is zero only for $d=4$. In $d=4$, then, free Maxwell theory is scale invariant and conformally invariant. For $d \neq 4$, it is only scale invariant.

Comment: You are so correct, what I meant was the the latter one. How do explicitly get the term $\frac{4-D}{4}$?

Comment: @Carl Where exactly are you having the problem in obtaining that?

Comment: $$ 
tr(T) = T^i_i = \frac{1}{4 \pi} (F^{i \mu}F_{i \mu} - \frac{1}{4 \pi} F^{\mu \nu}F_{\mu \nu})
$$

From here I am not really sure what to do. I set $i = \mu = \nu $ in order to get the diagonal elements.
For example the first element; $i = \mu = \nu = 0 $
$$
T^0_0 = \frac{1}{4 \pi}(F^{00}F_{00}-\frac{1}{4 \pi}F^{00}F_{00}) = \frac{1}{4 \pi} (\frac{4F^{00}F_{00}-F^{00}F_{00}}{4})
$$

Comment: @Carl That's not how you calculate the trace. Taking the trace of a tensor involves contraction of indices. And contraction means summation. You don't need to put $\mu =0 \cdots$. In my first equation, put $\alpha = \beta$ and sum over the dummy indices. What do you get?

Comment: $$
T^\alpha_\alpha = \frac{1}{4 \pi}(F^{\alpha \mu}F_{\alpha \mu} - \frac{1}{4}\delta^\alpha_\alpha F^{\mu \nu}F_{\mu \nu})
$$
I can't really see how the summation works here.

Comment: @Carl Almost there. $\delta^\alpha_\alpha = \delta^0_0 + \delta^1_1 + \cdots = d$

Comment: Thank you dearly. Now I understand the part with $\delta$. How is it possible to get the following?
$$
F^{\alpha \mu}F_{\alpha \mu} \rightarrow F^{ \mu \nu}F_{ \mu \nu}?
$$

Comment: @Carl It seems to me that you're not so comfortable with tensors. I suggest you work through tensorial expressions (like these) before you get used to them (which will not take much time). Note that $\alpha, \mu, \nu$ are all dummy indices. So both expressions are actually the same. If you're still not convinced, write down the first few terms of both expressions; they will match, and you should be able to see the pattern.

Comment: Are you sure that the overall constant would remain the same in higher dimensional ED? To me $4\pi$ hints at $S_2$, which is tied to a 4D spacetime.

Comment: I've been aware of this result but a friend of mine pointed out to me a question related to the same that I had overlooked. Since the electromagnetic field is massless in all dimensions, what sets the scale of the problem in dimensions other than $4$ when the theory is not conformally invariant? I think there should be some easy answer if I write it out as to how a conformal transformation acts on the EOM, but due to my laziness, I'd like to fish for a quick help here. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The electromagnetic tensor $F$ is the exterior derivative of the one-form $A$.  This makes it a two-form, which is antisymmetric (and thus traceless) by definition, completely independent of the number of spacetime dimensions involved.