# What sets the scale of a free Maxwell theory in $d\neq 4$?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, spacetime-dimensions, scale-invariance

The action for the free Maxwell theory is given by $$S=\int d^dx\sqrt{-g}\bigg(-\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}\bigg)$$
The theory is invariant under conformal transformations $g_{\mu\nu}\to\Omega^2(x)g_{\mu\nu}$ only in $d=4$ as can be recognized by looking at [the trace of the energy-momentum tensor of the theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/440570/), or more directly by recognizing that under such a transformation,

- $F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}=F_{\mu\nu}F_{\alpha\beta}g^{\alpha\mu}g^{\beta\nu}\to \Omega^{-4}F_{\mu\nu}F_{\alpha\beta}g^{\alpha\mu}g^{\beta\nu}=\Omega^{-4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}$
- $g=e^{\text{Tr}(\ln(g_{\mu\nu}))}\to e^{\text{Tr}(\ln(\Omega^2g_{\mu\nu}))}=e^{\text{Tr}(2\ln(\Omega))}g=e^{2d\ln(\Omega)}g=\Omega^{2d}g$

and thus, for $-\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{-g}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}$ to be invariant, $\frac{\Omega^{d}}{\Omega^4}=1$ which is the case only in $d=4$.

This means that the free Maxwell theory is not conformally invariant except in $d=4$. However, the definition of theory is the same in all dimensions and doesn't involve any dimensionful parameter, so I am confused as to what sets the scale of the problem in $d\neq 4$ when the theory is not conformally invariant.

Comment: To me, the question is unclear. In $d=4$, free Maxwell theory is conformally invariant so there are no meaningful scales to speak of. It's not uncommon for conformal invariance to strongly depend on the dimension of the space(-time).

Comment: What is the question? What is the conformal invariant theory in arbitrary d?

Comment: @Andrew I realize that conformal invariance of theories depends on the dimension of spacetime but my question is that if the theory is not invariant then there should be some parameters of the theory which give me a characteristic scale. In an interacting theory, this might be coupling constants, in a free theory, this might be the mass. But I am not sure how I would get a characteristic scale of a massless free theory.

Comment: @ApolloRa Thanks for the edit and the answer. Kindly see my above comment addressed at Andrew. I will have a look at the paper you linked to in your answer, but quickly, why do we have a $k/4$ here? The kinetic term would simply be a quadratic term, why introduce a parameter in the exponent? Apologies if these are naive objections.

Comment: Oh I see, so the question is, in $d \neq 4$, what is the scale for Maxwell theory? In that case the answer is that Maxwell's theory is **scale invariant** in any $d$, but is not **conformally invariant** (except in $d=4$). So, there is no physical scale, but also no conformal invariance.

Comment: @DvijD.C. Oh, ok my answer is not what you are looking for! Here's the link to the paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0008138, i will delete the answer as irrelevant to the question!

Comment: @DvijD.C. There are theories where we modify the exponent in the kinetic term of the lagrangian called power Maxwell, or non-linear electrodynamics. It just seems that when $k$ and $d$ are the same this results to the vanishing of energy momentum tensor and conformal invariance. I may be wrong though, as i said i cannot find any literature on the subject.

Comment: @Andrew Ah, I see, of course! If $\Omega$ is simply a scale transformation and not the full conformal transformation, then even if it is not canceled out in the action (which is the case in $d\neq 4$), it would simply be a constant factor which would not participate in the differentiation and would leave the EOM invariant, right?

Comment: @DvijD.C. That is one argument. Another approach is to choose the scaling dimension of the field so that the kinetic term is invariant. The main point is that scale invariance does not imply conformal invariance.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, I had sloppily assumed in the back of my mind that in physics, both always coincide. But I realize that there is a special conformal group that need not be a symmetry group just because the dilatation group is a symmetry group. And clearly, this is a manifest example. I would be glad to accept your answer if you compile your comments into an answer. I guess in QFT they usually coincide due to some peculiar workings of RG flows.

Comment: @DvijD.C. That's right, in QFT it is very hard to have scale invariance at all, since essentially any renormalization scheme will introduce a scale. (See dimensional transmutation in QCD). So the theories that do end up preserving scale invariance quantum mechanically have to be very special and symmetric, and often just end up being fully conformally invariant (eg $N=4$ super yang mills).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maxwell's theory is scale invariant in any , but is not conformally invariant (except in =4). So, there is no physical scale, but also no conformal invariance. Scale invariance does not imply conformal invariance.

One way to see this is to note that if Ω is simply a scale transformation and not the full conformal transformation, then even if it is not canceled out in the action (which is the case in ≠4), it would simply be a constant factor which would not participate in the differentiation and would leave the EOM invariant. Another approach is to choose the scaling dimension of the field so that the kinetic term is invariant.

In QFT it is very hard to have scale invariance at all, since essentially any regularization scheme will introduce a scale. (See dimensional transmutation in QCD). So the theories that do end up preserving scale invariance quantum mechanically have to be very special and symmetric, and often just end up being fully conformally invariant (eg =4 super yang mills).